# TensorFlow 2 LSTM produces only 1 prediction

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I have a dataset of shape (77424, 144). I then create a copy that is shifted up 1, and a version shifted up 2, and stack them together into a 77422, 3, 144 3d array.

So, the observation 2/3/4 in timestep 0 looks like this, where the first 4 columns are year/month/day/hour:

```
      0     1     2     3        4    ...   139   140   141   142  143
2      2011.0  12.0  31.0  21.0  13911.0  ...  0.00  0.11  38.0  36.0  9.0
3      2011.0  12.0  31.0  20.0  14635.0  ...  0.00  0.20  38.0  36.0  9.0
4      2011.0  12.0  31.0  19.0  15254.0  ...  0.00  0.18  38.0  36.0  9.0
```

Then at timestep 1, this is how it looks:

```
      0     1     2     3        4    ...  139   140   141   142  143
2      2011.0  12.0  31.0  22.0  13100.0  ...  0.0  0.17  38.0  35.0  9.0
3      2011.0  12.0  31.0  21.0  13911.0  ...  0.0  0.11  38.0  36.0  9.0
4      2011.0  12.0  31.0  20.0  14635.0  ...  0.0  0.20  38.0  36.0  9.0
```

As you might have guessed, timestep 2 looks like this:

```
      0     1     2     3        4    ...  139   140   141   142  143
2      2011.0  12.0  31.0  23.0  12410.0  ...  0.0  0.25  39.0  35.0  9.0
3      2011.0  12.0  31.0  22.0  13100.0  ...  0.0  0.17  38.0  35.0  9.0
4      2011.0  12.0  31.0  21.0  13911.0  ...  0.0  0.11  38.0  36.0  9.0
```

Then I feed this 3-D 77422, 3, 144 array into an LSTM, but I get really bad results. Specifically, the network is:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
tf.keras.layers.LSTM(50),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()

model.compile(loss='mse',
            optimizer=optimizer,
            metrics=['mae', 'mse'], epochs=50, verbose=0)
```

The thing I'm trying to predict is in the general range of 1,100 to 1,400. I am getting an MAE of like 1,200. My predictions are all the same number. So if I do this:

```
predictions = model.predict(X_test)
print(predictions)
```

I am getting:

```
[[62.61828]
 [62.61828]
 [62.61828]
 ...
 [62.61828]
 [62.61828]
 [62.61828]]
```

I have tried:

- Reversing the order the timesteps are stacked
- Reversing the order of the observations so the newest (2018) are on top and the oldest are at bottom
- Altering the number of neurons in the LSTM
- Tried a GRU with virtually identical results
- I have carefully ensured that I'm flipping my Y vector (the variable I'm trying to predict) to match the various flips of the input data.

So far my best solution is to build a huge table that pastes t-1 and t-2 onto the right side of the observations, so I wind up with a 2-D 77424, 432 array, then predicting with a regular multi-layer Dense model, but I feel like that's not the best solution since my data is time series data.

Can anyone advise on what I might be doing wrong here?

Thank you!

Comment: Your loss is too high, this means that the model has not learned or not trained enough, it makes no sense to look at the predictions in this case.

Comment: I was using that to diagnose why my loss would be so high, and that does explain it. The question is why the model predicts the same value on every input. If I use the same amount of data to train other types of models, I get good results. This makes me suspect I'm using the LSTM incorrectly rather than I don't have enough data.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it's stuck at that value, but maybe 1000 and 1400 are way beyond what the model/optimizer expects for training.

One idea is to try an `'sgd'` optimizer to see whether Adam is clipping something.

The other idea is to use a model that makes your Dense output a value that is more like the expected (around 0 and 1).

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
tf.keras.layers.LSTM(50),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(1),
tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: 300*x + 1100)
])
```

You could also enforce the output between 1000 and 1500 with:

```
tf.keras.layers.LSTM(50),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'),
tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: 500*x + 1000)
])
```